# How to synchronize data between devices using Google Datastore?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

Now, I save data in datastore of google cloud.

module-backend

```
@Entity
public class ComprarProducto {

    @Id
    private String producto;
    private boolean comprado;


    public ComprarProducto() {
    }

    public ComprarProducto(String producto) {
        this.producto = producto;

        this.comprado = false;

    }
...
}
```

[Example data of CompraProducto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dowc.jpg)

This data is displayed in a listview. When I add one item, the list is updated and saved in datastore.For save data I use AsyncTask in app.
Then, If I add one item in device1, I want to see that listview as both device1 as device2 is updated, but I don't know how to do it.

I use too GCM (google cloud messaging) and I've got to send a message to devices but only this. I want to see the data update in the device 2 without taking any action.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see the data update in the device 2 without taking any
>   action.

This is not possible without somehow notifying from the backend server that new data has been saved to datastore. Sending a push notification to device2 (or all other devices or whatever) would definitely be the correct way to do it. What you do is have the push notification tell device2 to query datastore.

If you really don't want to use GCM you COULD have device2 just query datastore every couple minutes but that is not recommended. The correct way to do it is to use GCM to give your device2 a "tickle" to indicate that there is new data in datastore and to query accordingly.

Not sure what kind of app you are building but these are some options.

Comment: I want use notification from the backend, but How send request from a client? In documentation of GCM only It's written about receive messages but not send from client andriod

Comment: You need to set up an API method which has code in it to send a GCM notification. Then, when your client executes that API method, the notification will be sent. Your client must first register with GCM before you can do that though because you need the client regId to be able to send push notifications to it. If you are using Android Studio, create a new project and then add a GAE with GCM module to it. It will generate sample code in the backend package with some API methods to register/send GCM notifications to a client. That may serve as a good starting point for you.